# tree questions to find diameter given number of nodes at each level

Tags: tree

Suppose at the first level of a tree a root node is always present. You are given an array count where count[i] denotes the number of nodes present at the ith level. We need to output the maximum diameter(number of edges in the longest path) possible for this tree

Comment: I think you should add some details: what language do you use, whant have you tried, what was wrong. This may help too: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: CPP is the language i used i have tried the approach 2*max_level but that fails

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific in my comment. I meant you should write the question better. Include meaningfull details. Describe what you have tried and why it is not what you need. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which may help you to make a better question.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Tested with some test cases.
Given: No of nodes at each level(1 to n-1), where level starts from 0, in an array. example - [1, 2, 2].
level_nodes - array having nodes at each level.
Return - Max diameter.

The tree has to be created in a way, which creates the max diameter.

The diameter of a tree is the longest path from 1 node to another node in a tree.

This has to be solved recursively, whenever level_nodes[i] is 1. Two values will be returned. One value is max diameter length for our current root node and another value is single path length.
for example -

```
    a
   / \
  b   c
 /
d
```

here for root node 'a', diameter length is 3(d-b-a-c, 3 edges) and single max path length is dba(d-b-a, 2 edges).

Please see the code(python) and let me know if anything not clear.

```
def get_max_diameters(i, level_nodes):
    if i >= len(level_nodes):
        return 0, 0
    max_diam_len = 0
    while i < len(level_nodes) and level_nodes[i] > 1:
        max_diam_len += 2 
        i += 1
    path_len = max_diam_len // 2
    if i < len(level_nodes):
        # Whenever encountered a level nodes with value 1, recurse and find diameter of current root node.
        i_node_diam, i_path_len = get_max_diameters(i + 1, level_nodes)
        i_path_len += 1
        return max(i_node_diam, i_path_len + max_diam_len), i_path_len + path_len
    return max(max_diam_len, path_len), path_len
```